# How to set a color variable in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, saas

I have an array of colors from which i generate a random color to style the text color, background color, etc. Now, want to use that particular color to design my elements. How do i do that.

We basically do this to make a heading red

`const element = <h1 style={{ color: 'red' }}>Hello world</h1>`

But I want to do something like this (this is wrong code its just for explaining my problem)

```
const colorvar="red"
const element = <h1 style={{ color: {colorvar} }}>Hello world</h1>
```

please help me with a solution.

Comment: Remove brackets around `colorvar`.

Comment: it worked thanks. I am a beginner in react. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style prop is an object containing key value pairs of styles (e.g. color, margin):

```
const style = { color: colorvar }
<div style={style} />
```

The issue in your code is that you wrap `colorvar` in brackets, resulting in:

```
const style = { color: { colorvar: colorvar } }
```

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer to mark your question resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should not wrap the variable with curly braces.

This will work.

```
const element = <h1 style={{ color: colorvar }}>Hello world</h1>
```